# O que fazer com a tag htacess?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

O que podemos fazer com a tag [htacess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htacess)? Na minha opinião podia ser um sinónimo da tag [htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess), pelo que me parece vai acontecer mais vezes esse erro.

Ou podemos simplesmente editar as perguntas em que a tag foi adicionada erradamente.

Comment: Claro que concordo totalmente com a visão do @bigown, ainda sim é um bom exemplo que temos que aumentar o score minimo para poder se criar uma tag http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635, dá muito problema (apesar de outras comunidades também usarem entre 150 e 300 como minimo). Levantar 1500 não é tão dificil para quem participa no SOpt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Que htacess? :D

Quando é erro de digitação costuma ser interessante criar um sinônimo porque é provável que ocorra de novo, não vejo ganho em fazer diferente.

Comment: Acho que é isso.